# Qt5 кроскомпиляция из под Windows в ARM

Tags: windows, qt, qt5, arm, кросс-компиляция

Пытаюсь настроить Qt Creator (qt5.10.1) что бы можно было компилировать в нём проекты для ARM систем.

Но не знаю с чего начать, в интернете много каких-то мануалов, но все они не понятны и сложны.

Почему надо делать множество настроек (лезть  в конфиги кумейк.конф), когда можно было бы создать простейший установщик и не париться?

---

Установил

> gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update-win32.exe

Прописал компилятор С:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (директория ..\GNU_Tools_Arm_Embedded\7_2018-q2-update\bin)

Прописал компилятор С++:

> arm-none-eabi-g++.exe (директория ..\GNU_Tools_Arm_Embedded\7_2018-q2-update\bin)

Прописал отладчик:

> \GNU_Tools_Arm_Embedded\7_2018-q2-update\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe

Но где взять `СMake`? Где взять профиль Qt (для `gcc-arm-а`)?

---

Учёл ответ Павла и попробовал для начала собрать Qt из исходников по [примеру](http://codedchaos.blogspot.com/2012/08/qt-mingw.html)  (для начало на винду)

```
C:\Qt\qt5\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\configure -platform ARM
+cd qtbase
+C:\Qt\qt5\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level -platform ARM 
Host platform 'ARM' is invalid. Aborting.
```

Попробовал так :

```
call configure.bat  -recheck-all -static -release -prefix C:\Qt\qt5\qt-relise-5_10_1 -opensource -confirm-license -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

Но увы снова не заработало

```
Cannot detect host toolchain. Please use -platform. Aborting.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Дополнил вызовом `-platform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно собрать Qt из исходников под вашу целевую операционную систему, либо попробовать найти у кого-то уже собранный. Обратите внимание: не для конкретного процессора, а для процессора+ОС.

Comment: а как это сделать ?? А то я несмог найти примера простейшего ;_; смог только "очертания" найти

Comment: для какой системы?

Comment: работаю в виндовс 7 (проц. интел) , надо проц. кортекс + линукс

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: Qt для кросскомпиляции ARM-linux обычно собирают из под "большого" линукса, но я сам не собирал. Ищите на форумах. В configure должна быть опция "-xplatform ..."
  Допустимые варианты для xplatform смотрите в исходниках, в каталоге "qtbase\mkspecs", ваш видимо linux-arm-gnueabi-g++

Comment: Спасибо, а то я даже вернуть `configure -?` верхнюю часть вывода не могу (в cmd как то затирает либо я просто не знаю как) и поэтому начало даже не вижу, увы другие консоли повели себя даже хуже. Теперь пишет `Bootstrapping qmake ... "nmake" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.`

Comment: nmake это из visual studio

Comment: хрень, у  меня в системных переменных нету "visual studio" и на компе нету и поправде говоря не думал что она нужна.

Comment: в винде можно вместо VS установить mingw

Comment: я из винды и вещаю ;_;